# Laravel: PHP Fatal error: Class '...ServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line #

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been working on the same app for a little bit now, and I am moving it over to Laravel. This is not only my first experience with Laravel, but my first time using a PHP framework. It is awesome so far.

I have run into a problem in my testing, I am getting an error: `Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class '...ServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line #`

I am wondering what causes this error and how I can fix it . It gives me the direct line that is problematic. But I have no idea how to solve this issue.

I have tried a number of solutions including

```
composer install
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```

and others as well.

I have also attempted deleting the `compiled.php` file all together, but then it trips the same error on a different file. What is it causing this error, and how can I go about debugging it?

Thanks for help in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Try running the following command:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

If that gives you the same error, you'll have to manually delete the file:

```
rm app/bootstrap/compiled.php
```

For laravel 5.5.*
you can remove related ServiceProvider in this file

```
\bootstrap\cache\config.php
```

Comment: Sorry, no I hadn't seen that part of your answer. I will try that. Are there any serious repercussions to manually deleting this file ie. how do I restore it? (thanks for the intro help!)

Comment: @velvetpuma - No repercussions. To restore it, run `php artisan optimize --force`.

Comment: I feel like there is a further issue. This cleared the error for compiled.php but now when I run `php artisan optimize --force` I get an error about the same ServiceProvider missing from a different file (illuminate/foundation/providerrepository)... kinda weird? I created this Service Provider from scratch and linked it to my `app.php` conf file, perhaps thats my issue?